# great circle distance performance

Tags: c++, approximation, trigonometry, boost-geometry

in my c++ program at one point I need to calculate the distance between two spherical points (given in azimuth and elevation) on a sphere. 
This calculation needs to be done extremely often, but I don't require a high accuracy (1 degree should be enough). 
(The distances are in all ranges [0-180])

I used a profiler (valgrind) to look for bottlenecks. It turns out that 70% of my runtime is spend in my calculation of the great circle distance. In this function 60% of my time is spend calculating the sine or cosine or other trigonometric functions...

I tried different approaches: (all using namespace std;)

```
double tmp = sin(el1) * sin(el2) + cos(el1) * cos(el2) * cos(az1-az2);
double distance = acos(tmp);
```

or

```
typedef boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::spherical_equatorial<boost::geometry::radian> > spherical_point;
spherical_point p1(az2,el2);
spherical_point p2(az1,el2);
double distance = hv.apply(p1,p2); % here hv is a haversine<double> object
```

or

```
double daz_half = (az2 - az1)/2;
double del_half = (el2 - el1)/2;
double tel = sin(del_half);
double taz = sin(daz_half);
double a = tel*tel + cos(el2) * cos(el1) * taz * taz ;
double distance = 2*atan2(sqrt(a),sqrt(1-a));
```

all calculations lead to similar run times, which are spend in different trigonometric functions...

Does anybody know a good approximation for the great circle distance formula with reduced accuracy?

Or does anybody know how to speed up the calculation of sin cos acos atan2...

Does it make sense to precalc a own trigonometric function lookup table with reduced accuracy?

If yes, how should this best look like (binary search or linear, vector or set...)?

Comment: In embedded systems we normally use lookup tables for trig functions - I'd give that a try.

Comment: There was a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650797/implementing-table-lookup-based-trig-functions

Comment: What is your point data? If you don't create many points on the spot and each point has several distances calculated, you could pre-calculate the sines and cosines for each point's azimuth and elevation.

Comment: And perhaps you could save some calculations if you designed the algorithm around the big circle distance calculation so that it doesn't have to call the distance function so often. This depends, of course, on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your help... I have created a own lookup table, which was already a big improvement.

Comment: unluckily my point looks slightly different each times, so I cannot precalc it. I will play around a bit with lookup tables. Right now I have created a own class "lookup" with an static unordered map.

Comment: Take first two terms of the series expansion https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Trigonometric_functions

Comment: @user7431005: You should be able to do better than a map by generating uniformly spaced samples and looking up a value (or two for interpolation) with an array index from scaling the input.